# AJAX Call Not Sending Success Response

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

```
//MAKE AJAX CALL TO REPOPULATE TABLE
        var newData = 'page_number=1&type=2';

        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST', // HTTP method POST or GET
            url: 'http://www.myurl.net/form_validate.php', //Where to make Ajax calls
            dataType:'text', // Data type, HTML, json etc.
            data:newData, //post variables
            success:function(response){

                //REFORMAT UPON SUCCESSFUL AJAX CALL
                alert(response);

            },
            error:function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){
                alert(xhr + " " + ajaxOptions + " " + thrownError); //throw any errors
            }
        });
```

All I've put in my PHP file is:

```
<?php echo "test"; ?>
```

When I go straight to that file, it echoes 'test.' When I try to run the AJAX function on the click of a button it gives me the error:

```
[object Object] error
```

in an alert window. I've put the absolute URL to the file because I was thinking that the relative linking I was using was wrong but it now seems like it's some other issue. Am I overlooking a simple syntax error? Sorry if this is super basic but I can't seem to figure this out after working on it for a really long time. Thanks for your help.

Comment: I must ask just for debugging purposes, is jQuery loaded?

Comment: It is. The AJAX call is happening on the click of a button. It's giving me the error alert so jQuery is loading correctly. There's also other jQuery events happening on the page.

Comment: use `console.log()` instead of `alert()` for debugging, messages will appear on your browser's console (Ctrl+Shift+J to open it)

Comment: Is the url in the same domain?

Comment: @Sergio, yes URL is in the same domain. It's in the same folder as the JS file in fact. I initially tried relative linking but that didn't work.

Comment: @MxmastaMills Have you tried relative to root: `url: '/form_validate.php'`? Also, what is the `xhr.status`? And, have you checked your browser's Console? Most are good about explaning why the request failed.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is your absolute url . Some browsers have problems dealing with absolute urls, consider it as a cross-domain request and block it ***even if it's not a cross-domain request***. You should try with relative url instead

Comment: I had mentioned that I was previously using the relative path and that didn't work.

Comment: @MxmastaMills: could you check if the relative path was correct? I had this problem in the past when I used absolute urls, when I changed to relative urls, everything worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

The problem might be in the `url`, try with relative path instead of absolute.
You named the file was in the same folder as the `.js` file, so try

```
url: '/directory_path_to_the_same_folder_as_the_JS_file/form_validate.php',
```

Comment: I had that thought previously but that didn't work as well. I've just tried it again right now too and am receiving the same error message.

Comment: Hmmm, ok . What is the xhr.status?

Comment: I'm a bit new to this. How do I locate the xhr.status?

Comment: What says if you have `alert(xhr.status)`? if you have a modern nrowser you can press F12 to open console, there you have very good information. What browser do you use? @MxmastaMills

Comment: It's alerting the number 0 when I alert(xhr.status). I noticed that that is when the response text is empty? Perhaps it's not loading the PHP file correctly then?

Comment: @MxmastaMills, can you put the php file on the same directory and run it from there? also, just to keep it simple. Use only this in your php file: `<?php echo 'Hello'; die(); ?>`

Comment: the PHP file is in the same directory and I'm only echoing out the word 'test' in the file. I've just changed the function to have no directory (just file name) since it's in the same directory but still no dice...

Comment: Do you use the console? which browser do you have? @MxmastaMills

Answer (score 0):

Try using `done` with [jQuery.post instead](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/).

For example:

```
jQuery.post('form_validate.php', data).done(
        function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                            alert(jqXHR.responseText);

        }).fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    alert(jqXHR.responseText);

}).complete(function() {
    // Common code when request completes
});
```

Comment: The `success` ***option*** hasn't been deprecated. The `.success()` method of the returned `jqXHR` has been, as it was just an alias for [`.done()`](http://api.jquery.com/deferred.done/).

Answer (score 0):

- If your error is `[object Object] error NOT FOUND` then the reason is
  the specified url in AJAX is not correct.
- If your error is  `[object Object] error INTERNAL SERVER ERROR` , its
  because of the error in your server file ie the php file ,error like variables not defined correctly etc..
- Some times error may occur due to cross domain, if you have not
  specified headers when in case your php file is not in the same
  domain

Hope this helps

Thank you

Answer (score -2):

```
function abc(){
  var ret=true;
 $.ajax({
           type: 'POST',
           url: 'send_password.php',
           data: 'mail_to=mymail&new_password=pwd',
           async:false,
           success: function(response){

           },
           error: function(r){

               ret=false;
           }
       });
return ret;
}

    alert(abc());
```

Have a look at this [**testfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/vaibviad/Z8sRF/152/)

Comment: Um, unless I'm missing something, how do you expect to see the value set from an asynchronous callback immediately after issuing the ajax request?

Comment: I'm just getting 'false' alerted out when I look at this (as I figured I would)...